# cursor revealing image underneath

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm trying to figure out how I can have 2 images layered on top of each other, where moving the cursor reveals the image behind it with a spotlight effect.

I have a fiddle here with how I currently have it laid out with an image, and a dark overlay that just reveals the image without any overlay as you move your cursor, but I would like an image to be on top instead of just an overlay, while retaining the rest out of how it looks.

https://jsfiddle.net/koLa0gft/

```
<div class="section" >
<canvas id="canvas-overlay"></canvas>
<canvas id="canvas-lines"></canvas>
</div>

.section {
    background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1580587771525-78b9dba3b914?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80);
    background-size: cover;
    padding:200px 0;
}

#canvas-overlay {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      z-index: 1;
      opacity: 0.85;
}
#canvas-lines {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      z-index: 1;
      opacity: 0.05;
}

  var canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas-overlay');
  var canvasContext = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var lineCanvas = document.querySelector('#canvas-lines');
  var lineCanvasContext = lineCanvas.getContext('2d');
  var pointLifetime = 500;
  var points = [];

  //FILL CANVAS
  canvasContext.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)";
  canvasContext.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  //INIT
  function init() {
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
    window.addEventListener('resize', resizeCanvases);
    resizeCanvases();
    tick();
  }

  init();

  //RESIZE CANVAS
  function resizeCanvases() {
    canvas.width = lineCanvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    canvas.height = lineCanvas.height = window.innerHeight;
  }

  function onMouseMove(event) {
    points.push({
      time: Date.now(),
      x: event.clientX,
      y: event.clientY
    });
  }

  function tick() {
    // Remove old points
    points = points.filter(function(point) {
      var age = Date.now() - point.time;
      return age < pointLifetime;
    });

    drawLineCanvas();
    drawImageCanvas();
    requestAnimationFrame(tick);
    //setTimeout(() => {
    //tick();
    //}, 1000 / 60);
  }

  function drawLineCanvas() {
    var minimumLineWidth = 70;
    var maximumLineWidth = 140;
    var lineWidthRange = maximumLineWidth - minimumLineWidth;
    var maximumSpeed = 70;

    lineCanvasContext.clearRect(0, 0, lineCanvas.width, lineCanvas.height);
    lineCanvasContext.lineCap = 'round';
    lineCanvasContext.shadowBlur = 70;
    lineCanvasContext.shadowColor = '#000';

    for (var i = 1; i < points.length; i++) {
      var point = points[i];
      var previousPoint = points[i - 1];

      // Change line width based on speed
      var distance = getDistanceBetween(point, previousPoint);
      var speed = Math.max(0, Math.min(maximumSpeed, distance));
      var percentageLineWidth = (maximumSpeed - speed) / maximumSpeed;
      lineCanvasContext.lineWidth = minimumLineWidth + percentageLineWidth * lineWidthRange;

      // Fade points as they age
      var age = Date.now() - point.time;
      var opacity = (pointLifetime - age) / pointLifetime;
      lineCanvasContext.strokeStyle = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, ' + opacity + ')';

      lineCanvasContext.beginPath();
      lineCanvasContext.moveTo(previousPoint.x, previousPoint.y);
      lineCanvasContext.lineTo(point.x, point.y);
      lineCanvasContext.stroke();
    }
  }

  function getDistanceBetween(a, b) {
    return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(a.x - b.x, 2) + Math.pow(a.y - b.y, 2));
  }

  function drawImageCanvas() {
    canvasContext.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
    canvasContext.save();
    canvasContext.fillStyle = "rgb(0, 0, 0)";
    canvasContext.globalAlpha = 0.009;
    canvasContext.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    canvasContext.restore();
    canvasContext.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';
    canvasContext.drawImage(lineCanvas, 0, 0);

  }
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are incredibly close! Here's what I did to make it work.

```
// Added a new image for the sake of the demo.
var coverImage = new Image();
coverImage.src = 'https://i.picsum.photos/id/719/1000/750.jpg?hmac=jhV0AyBKhvg_tvhHIkS5i_V794dg391QMasWGLlRyNU';

// wait until the image loads then call init
coverImage.addEventListener('load', () => {init();});

// Modified drawImageCanvas to the following.

  function drawImageCanvas() {
    canvasContext.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
    canvasContext.save();
    // Primary change is to draw the image. Also removed the global alpha changes.
    canvasContext.drawImage(coverImage, 0, 0);
    canvasContext.restore();
    canvasContext.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';
    canvasContext.drawImage(lineCanvas, 0, 0);
  }
```

Just some minor CSS changes included in the full demo below.

```js
  var canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas-overlay');
  var canvasContext = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var lineCanvas = document.querySelector('#canvas-lines');
  var lineCanvasContext = lineCanvas.getContext('2d');
  var pointLifetime = 500;
  var points = [];
  
  var coverImage = new Image();
  coverImage.src = 'https://i.picsum.photos/id/719/1000/750.jpg?hmac=jhV0AyBKhvg_tvhHIkS5i_V794dg391QMasWGLlRyNU';

  //FILL CANVAS
  canvasContext.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)";
  canvasContext.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  //INIT
  function init() {
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
    window.addEventListener('resize', resizeCanvases);
    resizeCanvases();
    tick();
  }

    
  coverImage.addEventListener('load', () => {init();});


  //RESIZE CANVAS
  function resizeCanvases() {
    canvas.width = lineCanvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    canvas.height = lineCanvas.height = window.innerHeight;
  }

  function onMouseMove(event) {
    points.push({
      time: Date.now(),
      x: event.clientX,
      y: event.clientY
    });
  }

  function tick() {
    // Remove old points
    points = points.filter(function(point) {
      var age = Date.now() - point.time;
      return age < pointLifetime;
    });

    drawLineCanvas();
    drawImageCanvas();
    requestAnimationFrame(tick);
    //setTimeout(() => {
    //tick();
    //}, 1000 / 60);
  }

  function drawLineCanvas() {
    var minimumLineWidth = 70;
    var maximumLineWidth = 140;
    var lineWidthRange = maximumLineWidth - minimumLineWidth;
    var maximumSpeed = 70;

    lineCanvasContext.clearRect(0, 0, lineCanvas.width, lineCanvas.height);
    lineCanvasContext.lineCap = 'round';
    lineCanvasContext.shadowBlur = 70;
    lineCanvasContext.shadowColor = '#000';

    for (var i = 1; i < points.length; i++) {
      var point = points[i];
      var previousPoint = points[i - 1];

      // Change line width based on speed
      var distance = getDistanceBetween(point, previousPoint);
      var speed = Math.max(0, Math.min(maximumSpeed, distance));
      var percentageLineWidth = (maximumSpeed - speed) / maximumSpeed;
      lineCanvasContext.lineWidth = minimumLineWidth + percentageLineWidth * lineWidthRange;

      // Fade points as they age
      var age = Date.now() - point.time;
      var opacity = (pointLifetime - age) / pointLifetime;
      lineCanvasContext.strokeStyle = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, ' + opacity + ')';

      lineCanvasContext.beginPath();
      lineCanvasContext.moveTo(previousPoint.x, previousPoint.y);
      lineCanvasContext.lineTo(point.x, point.y);
      lineCanvasContext.stroke();
    }
  }

  function getDistanceBetween(a, b) {
    return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(a.x - b.x, 2) + Math.pow(a.y - b.y, 2));
  }

  function drawImageCanvas() {
    canvasContext.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
    canvasContext.save();
    canvasContext.drawImage(coverImage, 0, 0);
    canvasContext.restore();
    canvasContext.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';
    canvasContext.drawImage(lineCanvas, 0, 0);
  }
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.section {
    background: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1580587771525-78b9dba3b914?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80) no-repeat;
    background-size: 1000px 750px;
    padding:200px 0;
    height: 750px;
}

#canvas-overlay {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      z-index: 1;
      opacity: 1;
}
#canvas-lines {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      z-index: 1;
      opacity: 0.05;
}
```

```html
<div class="section" >
  <canvas id="canvas-overlay"></canvas>
  <canvas id="canvas-lines"></canvas>
</div>
```

This will at least get you where you want to be, however there are some other ways you can accomplish this. Here's a quick example using mostly CSS.

```js
const section = document.querySelector('section');
const mask = document.querySelector('.mask');

section.addEventListener('mousemove', (evt) => {
    mask.style.clipPath = `circle(60px at ${evt.clientX}px ${evt.clientY}px`;
});
```

```css
img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

section:hover > .mask {
  opacity: 1;
}

.mask {
  transition: opacity 0.2s;
  opacity: 0;
  clip-path: circle(0px at 0px 0px);
}
```

```html
<section>
  <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/929/500/500.jpg?hmac=IIJmK5O9ySao8tMORSmzopzHo0ycS0Q2W5LSZ97YNew" alt="image 1">
  <img class="mask" 
    src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/220/500/500.jpg?hmac=BI2JJ-HO8Y-sPg5VypbxvFcnn_kODMPs1eFverLVdD0" alt="image 2">
</section>
```

Comment: Awesome, that's exactly what I was trying to achieve! Thanks a lot. Also it's cool to see that I could have done that through CSS with a bit of js, I didn't know about the clip-path property.

Comment: I've been trying to do this for a while! This is excellent - how would I soften the edges of the clip-path? Sort of like a gradient opacity around the cursor instead of the hard lines (if that makes sense).
*Referring to your example using mostly css